Segmentaion fault (core dumped), what does it mean and how to fix
i'm working on the cs50 plurality problems from problems set, which require me to complete 2 functions for a voting system, but I keep getting the 'Segmentaion fault (core dumped)' error code, whenever i put in a vote for a person that is not a candidate. i don't know what it mean and don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help? Thank You!
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
} candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);
int pargc;
char **pargv;

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    pargc = argc;
    pargv = argv;
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    // TODO
    for(int i = 0; i < pargc; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    int num = 0;
    string winner[9];
    winner[0] = candidates[0].name;
    int win_votes = candidates[0].votes;

    for(int i = 0; i<pargc; i++)
    {
        if(win_votes < candidates[i+1].votes)
        {
            winner[0] = candidates[i+1].name;
        }
        else if(win_votes == candidates[i+1].votes)
        {
            winner[num+1] = candidates[i+1].name;
            num++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<num+1; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", winner[i]);
    }
}

I think my problem lies in the 'vote' function, but i'm not sure.

You have for(int i = 0; i < pargc; i++) in vote.  Compare the values of pargc and candidate_count and I think you'll find you're going one past the end of the array candidates.  Similar issue in print_winner.

Segmentation fault just means that your program is accessing memory that it shouldn't be accessing. Typical causes are array-out-of-bounds bugs, pointer-related bugs, non-initialized variables getting used, attempting to write to a string literal etc.
